# Have problems make two elements scroll at different speeds

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have uploaded all of my code to gitHub to help answer this question so you can see the whole code, repository - https://github.com/Matthammond96/Fail-Net

A live preview of the code - http://pcsmadeeasy.co.uk

I'm trying to make the background (id=par1, par2, par3") scroll faster than the content which has a classes called section. However the jQuery which I used isn't slowing it down (found at the bottom of the index.html). Im new to jQuery so can't work out the problem, any help would be useful thank you!

The html looks like this;

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper-scroll">
         <div id="par1"></div>
         <div id="par2"></div>
         <div id="par3"></div>
            <div class="content">

                <div class="section">

                    <div class="article1"> <!-- Epsiode 1 -->
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="article2"> <!-- Epsiode 2 -->


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="article3"> <!-- Epsiode 3 --> 

                            </div>
                        </div> 


                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the css that goes along with it is;

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper-scroll {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.content {
    width: 3862px;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -o-max-content;
    width: -ms-max-content;
    width: max-content;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: .3em 0;
}
.section {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 1.2em 0 0;
} 

#par1 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #db3ea5;
    display: inline-block;   
    z-index: -10;
}

#par2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:1400px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4b3edb;
    display: inline-block;  
    z-index: -10;
}

#par3 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:2800px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5dc1a;
    display: inline-block;  
    z-index: -10;
}

.article1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.article2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:1400px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
}

.article3 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:2800px;
    right:0px;
    width: 1400px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And then my jQuery which I'm using to change the speed is;

```
<script>
  function parralax() {
     var par2 = document.getElementById('par2');
     var par3 = document.getElementById('par3');
     par2.style.left = -(window.pageYOffset / 10)+'px';
     par3.style.left = -(window.pageYOffset / 10)+'px';
   }
   window.addEventListener("scroll", parralax, false);
   </script>

   <script>
     function parralax2() {
      var article2 = document.getElementById('article2');
      var article3 = document.getElementById('article3');
      article2.style.left = -(window.pageYOffset / 1)+'px';
      article3.style.left = -(window.pageYOffset / 1)+'px';
     }
     window.addEventListener("scroll", parralax2, false);
   </script>
```

Comment: Didn’t you post this question already? What happened to that one?

Comment: @Xufox Im new on here, but thanks will keep that in mind.